# what is the difference between **optimize** and **uniroot**?

Tags: r

I looked at the descriptions for uniroot and optimize and they are somewhat different but the book reference is the same and I am wondering if there are reasons to pick one over the other?

Comment: The Description section for [`uniroot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/uniroot.html) and [`optimize`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optimize.html) might give you some hint on how they are different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two functions have entirely different purposes:

- `optimize` is used to find the minimum (or maximum) of a function.
- `uniroot` is used to find the root (zero) of a function.

Comment: I'm down voting this answer because, while of course, trivially, this is a difference, the answer doesn't get at the heart of the OPs problem. A root finding can often be reformulated as an optimization. Uniroot only works when  f(left end point) is a different sign than f(right end point). This is not required for optimize. Optimize can be used to find a root when unitroot will fail, for example `uniroot(f=function(x){x^2-4}, interval =c(-10,10) )` vs. `optimize(f=function(x){(x^2-5)^2}, interval =c(-10,10) )`. You can check that the answer from optimize is a root by $objective

Comment: for me uniroot provides no such info, it just gives and error message 'f() values at end points not of opposite sign' it does not specify anything about multiple roots. And for example, `uniroot(f=function(x){x*(x^2-4)}, interval =c(-10,10) )` only finds one root despite there being multiple. So perhaps I am missing some arguments that you are including.

Answer (score 13):

As for reasons to pick one over the other. In (probably) most cases one will be more natural. As @shadow says `optimise` is for minimisation (or maximisation) and `uniroot` is for finding zero points.

In some cases however you can use either to solve your problem. This will often be because you can take derivatives but there could be another some other way to restructure your problem. The rest of this answer will talk about these cases where you actually have a choice and need to choose between the two cases.

For a simple example we may want to find the minimum of the function:

```
Func = function(x) {
  (2*x-pi)^2 + exp(1)*x - 18
}
```

One way to do this is to use `optimize` as:

```
OResult = optimize(Func, lower = 0, upper = 5)
OResult
$minimum
[1] 1.231011

$objective
[1] -14.19195
```

Another way is to transform the function by taking the derivative. As the optimum point is when the derivative is zero we need a root-finding algorithm like uniroot. So the function becomes:

```
DerivFunction = function(x) {
  4*(2*x-pi) + exp(1)
}
```

Which is optimized by:

```
UResult = uniroot(DerivFunction , interval = c(0,5))
UResult
$root
[1] 1.231011

$f.root
[1] 4.440892e-16

$iter
[1] 2

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 6.103516e-05
```

### Speed

If you are choosing between the above too approaches you would probably go with `optimize` for simplicity. There are cases in which `uniroot` may be faster however.

Using the above example the `optimize` function called the function 7 times while the uniroot only called the derivative function 5 times. (This can be found by putting counters in the above functions). This is logical, optimize doesn't know how low the minima is while uniroot does know to aim for a function value of zero. So uniroot will often know what direction to go in x axis whilst optimize will need to look around more.

If we do a benchmark optimize is much faster however.
So in general (if you are looking at speed) use optimize unless it is a very intensive function where function calls are more expensive than what the optimization algorithm is doing (of course in these cases often it will be very difficult to get a form of the problem to use `uniroot` on).

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  optimize(Func, lower = 0, upper = 5),
  uniroot(DerivFunction, interval = c(0,5))
)
Unit: microseconds
                                       expr    min     lq     mean  median     uq     max neval
       optimize(Func, lower = 0, upper = 5) 18.264 19.785 23.50664 20.7370 23.781 129.365   100
 uniroot(DerivFunction, interval = c(0, 5)) 63.161 67.346 74.10322 69.8195 76.858 143.062   100
```

### Multiple Local Optima

The optimize function may not find a global optima but merely a local optima. The same in true for `uniroot` which may find a local zero but not others that exist. `uniroot` is different from `optimize` however as while you set optimize to find either a maximum or a minimum, `uniroot` will find a point that crosses the y axis. If you `uniroot` for a derivative then this point could be a minima or a maxima.

For instance if we have the following function and derivative:

```
TwoMinFunction = function(x){
  ((x)^4)/4 + x^3 - 3*x^2 - 8*x + 16
}

TwoZeroDerivFunction = function(x){
  (x^3 + 3*x^2 − 6*x − 8) 
}
```

This function is as shown in the following figure:
[image: TwoMinimumFunction]

```
OResult = optimize(TwoMinFunction, lower = -6, upper = 4)
OResult
$minimum
[1] -4.000001

$objective
[1] 8.007817e-12

UResult = uniroot(TwoZeroDerivFunction , interval = c(-6,4))
UResult
$root
[1] -1

$f.root
[1] 0

$iter
[1] 1

$init.it
[1] NA

$estim.prec
[1] 5
```

What happened here is that optimize found one of the two minima. The uniroot function on the other hand found a maxima (as uniroot cannot differentiate between minima and maxima).